# How to add hyperlinks to Text columns in Fusion Tables?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

As I enter data into a TEXT column in my fusion tables, I find that while I can use html formatting in the text column, the hyperlinks don't display properly in the info balloons.

For example:

```
    <p>See specimen record  at <a href="http://janzen.sas.upenn.edu/">Caterpillars</a>
```

This is read simply as **See specimen record at Caterpillers**, with the link stripped out.

Is there a way to add hyperlinked text into the database?

Please note: I know it is possible to to add hyperlinked text in the CONFIGURE INFO WINDOW area, but then that link appears for every marker. I want to add different links for different markers.

Thanks!
Wendy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rod's answer is correct but I'm guessing you are having a different problem, which is what is the list of columns being displayed by the default infoWindow? You must check the list of columns in the CONFIGURE INFO WINDOW dialog to ensure that your column with the link is checked.  I think the default is only the first several columns. Don't worry about formatting the info window just the checkboxes.

Comment: I am happy (and embarrassed) to say that you are all correct. I created a new file and did some testing and found that links do work, whether they are categorized as Text/None or Text/Link. My original problem was the result of a coding error on my part. Important to note that the target=blank line must be added to the url or the visitor will click away from the map. Example of well-formed hyperlinked text:       See specimen record at <a href="http://janzen.sas.upenn.edu/" target="_blank">Caterpillars</a>.   Thanks very much for your fast responses. @Rod McChesney

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<p>See specimen record  at <a href="http://janzen.sas.upenn.edu/" target="_blank">Caterpillars</a>
```

This will cause the link to open in a new window or tab rather than taking over the map, and should not get scrubbed from the info window HTML.

Comment: Thanks Rod, but I did try this. The problem is not the link taking over the window, but it is not being read at all.

Answer (score 1):

One other possible option is to add a column with the links for each info window. Then, when configuring the content of the info windows, use a template like the following:

```
<p>See specimen record at <a href="{<link_column_name>}">Caterpillar</a></p>
```

Substitute `<link_column_name>` with the column that contains the links.